# How can I upsert a homogeneous List<SObject>, in a good way?

Tags: apex, sobject, upsert, generics, abstract

I have some abstracted code, which at the end of some process will create a homogeneous list of SObjects.

It could be a list of Accounts, it could be a list of contacts, it could be a list of some custom SObject.  It doesn't matter, every record in the list will be an instance of the same type of SObject.

```
upsert resultSObjectList
```

I can't simply do an because it results in:

> System.TypeException: DML on generic List only allowed for insert, update or delete

If I send the list back to whatever method called my abstraction and then try to cast it back into whatever type it should be, e.g.:

```
List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>) resultSObjectList;
upsert accountList;
```

It *still* results in:

> System.TypeException: DML on generic List only allowed for insert, update or delete

I **can** make this work with:

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
for (SObject sObj : resultSObjectList) {
    accountList.add((Account) sObj);
}
upsert accountList;
```

But that is ugly and I will need to make a similar implementation for every consumer of my process.

*Likewise, I'd prefer not to create two separate lists (for insert and for update) and then do two separate DML operations.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the actual object to be a concrete sobject list type. You can do it either by Type.forName or by String.

```
SObject[] results = doUpsert(source, List<Account>.class);

...

public SObject[] doUpsert(Sobject[] source, Type listType) {
  SObject[] results = (SObject[])listType.newInstance();
  results.addAll(source);
  upsert results;
  return results;
}
```

---

```
Sobject[] results = doUpsert(source, 'List<Account>');

...

public SObject[] doUpsert(Sobject[] source, String listType) {
  SObject[] results = (SObject[])Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
  results.addAll(source);
  upsert results;
  return results;
}
```

Either way, these are pretty efficient ways to get things done.

---

Edit: Based on comments, the following should also be acceptable:

```
public SObject[] doUpsert(Sobject[] source) {
  if(source != null && source.size() > 0) {
    String listType = 'List<'+source[0].getSObjectType()+'>';
    SObject[] results = (SObject[])Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
    results.addAll(source);
    upsert results;
    return results;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is bit ugly, but serializing and deserializing converts sObject to the actual type they are.

```
List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(resultSObjectList),List<Account>.class);
upsert accountList;
```

The above code works.

Comment: It works, but incredibly CPU hungry.